# Grab URL as file upload for Drupal 7?

Tags: files

When creating a content type, you have the option of adding a "file upload" field. How can I extend the functionality of this upload file to allow for the option of simply entering a URL instead of manually downloading the file and uploading it again? I basically want another field, called URL, where I enter the URL of the image. Drupal must then grab the URL as if though I uploaded it. Which means I must be able to "press upload" and actually see the thumbnail as per normal functionality.

I have a site from which we often grab images, but every time I first have to download it. It would save me a lot of trouble if I could just provide the URL and let Drupal do its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [FileField Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module:

> FileField Sources is an extension to the FileField module. The FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means, including:
>
> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - **Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)**
> - Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

Emphasis mine.